# Document Library Required Columns

Tags: document-library, column

I'm trying to organize a document library by using different columns of information.  I have two columns that are drop-down menus and one column that is a single line of text, all of which I set to be required.  However, when a new document is uploaded, it automatically takes on the default values for those fields, rather than allowing the user to fill out those values.  Is there a way to prevent users from uploading documents unless all the required columns are filled out?

Comment: Are you drag and drop or manually upload document from ribbon or New button in list view?

Comment: I'm talking about manually uploading from the ribbon or New button, not drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

In document library item is only created once you upload the document to it, so you cannot go vise versa but if you want,

You can try the column validation for validating the document library.
For example :-`=IF([Column1]="Vietzen", "OK", "Not OK")`.

But with this won't stop the document from uploading but can validate other fields.